# .NET Repository Pattern and Http Requests

Tags: .net, architecture, repository-pattern

I am trying to 100% understand the patterns of architecture in the .NET world. The Repository main code of the Repository Pattern as far as i know is usually created in the infrastructure layer, for data access, not only to databases but other cases as well. To this day, i've only seen it being used for access to the database, but i would like to see if possible, multiple other examples for when using a Repository class.

Right now for example, i'm building an application that does Http Requests to multiple other APIs. I have a Domain/Core layer, and an Infrastructure layer. What would be the best practice in this case for the Http Requests class? Should there be Repositories for the HttpRequests communication classes? Or is there another pattern to follow in this case?

If possible and someone could give some more detailed material on this subject i would be thankful. I have searched a lot and all i can find is always the same database only related repository access.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the best practices for this kind of a usecase, but recently I have build something similar. So basically I have folder named externalRepositories inside Infrastructure project which contains mainly three things (per host):

`SomeHostHttpClient` - maybe not necessarily in your case, but I'm using it for authentication, retries in case of 401/403 and logs requests/responses

`SomeHostExternalRepository` - handles api requests for a host, checks the response and deserializes object.

`SomeHostMappingService` - used to map from response dto to entity with additional requests to db for references and so on. Probably this should be inside external repository as private merhods and repo should return entities, I just wanted to separate these two by their responsibilities. But now it introduces some confusion and additional knowledge of implementation

Not saying that it is the correct solution, just sharing my experience within this topic.